# How to mitigate, or reduce, several second "cut-offs" for wireless network extenders?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a [TP-Link RE200](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/range-extender/re200/) wireless range extender that got me pretty excited initially. After several days of use I started getting a lot of complaints from network users about slowness issues and loss of Internet, etc.

Once I started to investigate the issue I found that users who mostly noticed this were doing some kind of transaction on a website, watching a video (YouTube or Netflix), playing a game (just about any game that requires a stable Internet connection) or on a VoIP call.

I contacted the manufacturer and they replied that their devices don't support 802.11r and they simply suggested using the same SSID as the host AP - which we're already doing. They said the following:

> Sorry for the trouble caused. Since RE200 doesn't apply 802.11r
>   agreement, so currently it doesn't support fast roaming. When the
>   devices switch from the host network to the extended network, there
>   must be several seconds cut-off.

It got me thinking about other scenarios and ideas of perhaps using a DIFFERENT SSID or playing with channels, etc.

Are there any proven ways to mitigate or at least reduce the several second cut-off / changeover time required to flip between the primary access point and the range extending access point?

Comment: 802.11r is for fast handoffs, so I guess the answer is "use only hardware that supports 802.11r"? And since you are talking about "users" (plural), I assume the installation is large enough that a wired backbone for all APs would make sense.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting @dirkt. The main AP is running DD-WRT, would running a wired backbone with another AP with the same SSID in some fashion be able to mitigate this? Do you have a link or some details you could share?

Comment: From what I'm gathering 802.11r is not a silver bullet since it seems that a lot of hardware may not support it on the client side (aside from the actual router / AP side), so it would seem that perhaps you're thinking of a wired backbone as, in some way, making the "cut-off" or switch over from one AP to the other might be markedly reduced?  I guess this is where I'm very interested in additional thoughts and information here.

Comment: You don't need 802.11r to stop the handover lag, can you put the second router in AP mode? Or do you have another router to use? Is wiring the second router an option?

Comment: Putting a second router into AP mode is an option - and I could even theoretically wire it (might be a little tricky for the location, but doable) @Tim_Stewart. Do you have something in mind that would even keep the same SSID for seamless handoff?

Comment: Yep, https://superuser.com/questions/1305544/multiple-access-points-switching-issues/1305550#1305550

Comment: Let me know if you run into issues