# wireless extenders USED AS wireless access points

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point

please help me out!!!!

I live in this three-story building,
one household basically.
I have 500mbps with OPTIMUM (only choice in the neighborhood..sucks!)

basically we have main line of internet on the 2nd floor and 1st and 3rd floor is using the networks off of it.

So the setup I have now is
3rd floor: using wifi off of 2nd floor + LINKSYS RE6300 AC1200 wifi extender for dead zones
==>8-10mbps for using wifi extender in the dead zones and upto 90mbps for using wifi off of 2nd floor

2nd floor: MAIN MODEM and ROUTER (Linksys mr9000 AC3000 allowing upto 25 devices) ===>upto 420mbps

1st floor: using wifi off of 2nd floor + NETGEAR wn3000rpv3 wifi repeater for dead zones
==> 20mbps for dead zones with NETGEAR repeater, and 240 mbps for using 2nd floor wifi

but I have this extra D-LINK DIR866L from optimum cable which I don't use (because i replaced it with LINKSYS MR9000 AC3000)
(and can also exchange it to SAGEMCOM optimum router anytime for free, Sagemcom is supposed to faster than DLINK DIR866L)

so 1st and 3rd floor are using wifi extender (UNWIRED) and leeching off of 2nd floor signal, pretty much
and this has not been too stable, so,
I am trying to WIRE everything (with ethernet cable) and use the extenders AS WIRELESS ACCESS POINTS (WAP)

SAGEMCOM or D-LINK DIR866L router as the 1st floor WAP
and LINKSYS RE6300 AC 1200 as the 3rd floor WAP

and obviously these will be both WIRED with CAT 7 ethernet cable from 2nd floor main router
(or should I connect it straight from the modem?)

How does this sound?
at the end of the day, it will be like

3rd floor: using wifi off of 2nd floor + LINKSYS RE6300 AC1200 WIRED to main modem/router from 2nd floor
2nd floor: MAIN MODEM and ROUTER (Linksys mr9000 AC3000)
1st floor: using wifi off of 2nd floor + SAGEMCOM or D-LINK router WIRED to main modem/router from 2nd floor

does this sound plausible?
or would it deteriorate the whole signal power for the entire building?

Usually WAPs are better than Wifi Repeater/extenders, no?

Please help me out, thanks!!

Comment: I avoid wireless extenders because they reduce bandwidth  - outer point talks back to inner point. Try to fish Ethernet to the top floor so as to have a true wired Access Point. That is what I was able to do.

Comment: You are going to run into one problem.  Each time you extend the initial network, with a network extender, any device connected to the extender will see decreased speeds.  This decrease in speeds will only happen if you are extended the network wirelessly obviously.  Wireless extenders are not all created equal, some support the setup you describe, some do not support it.  You will have to determine if your hardware does support the setup you describe. **I personally would just purchase a switch for each floor, then connect a router to the switch, to provide wireless internet on the floor.**

Comment: Thanks John and Ramhound. Yes, I want to stay away from just EXTENDING signals, I am trying to hire a OPTIMUM technician to WIRED the extenders as ACCESS POINTS with CAT7 RJ45 ethernet cables. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using CAT7?  Its a bit of a nonsense - and is not a ratified standard.  Save your money and use CAT6A.  If you are worried about futureproofing ask the installers to add a pull-wire!  (My wholesaler that specializes in data cabling and products does not sell any CAT7 cables or products.)

Comment: @davidgo you are right. I heard from other ppl not to use CAT7, I returned that and bought legit cables at HOME DEPOT (they only had CAT6 and 5E of shorter length, so I had to go with CAT 6)

Answer (score 1):

WAPS are better then repeaters (repeaters being the worst commonly used solution - they waste a lot of bandwidth).

I would configure the secondary routers as AP(s) - ie ignore WAN port and disable DHCP on then) and plug these all into your 1 central router.   In this way, as long as you have your equipment on non overlapping WIFI channels, and have the same SSID, authentication method and password on all your device you will be able to roam between areas and it will be nearly  (but not properly) seamless.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer!! I am still trying to learn HOW TO have same SSID, while have non-overlapping WIFI channels...do you have any good link for this solution?

Comment: I don't, but its quite straightforward.  You just put the same AP name for each AP, and same password.  If you are using 2.4 gig band, you use the channels 1, 6 and 11.

Comment: @thebannerever, incase you didn't figure it out. https://superuser.com/questions/1305544/multiple-access-points-switching-issues/1305550#1305550

Answer (score 0):

I have my network in the basement, household office on the main floor and my office on the top floor.

I ran Ethernet from the basement through a closet (conduit in the corner) to the top floor.

I have a Ubiquiti Access point (POE connection at the main router in the basement).  I get top ISP speed this way on the top floor (and on the main floor) and fast LAN access between devices. Ubiquiti is special purpose and is as good as a router - Routers are good as Access Points as well (more than one way to do things). Ubiquiti (one point) works like a mesh so roaming is excellent).

Ethernet backbone is to be vastly preferred to Extenders.

I trust this helps you.

Comment: yeah, I really hope I have a hole of some sort to have ethernet go through it, so I have to do the old method - ethernet through pierced window frame and prop the cable to other floors..

Comment: There are several approaches to routing Ethernet depending on the building construction ,