# How to get wifi to the far end of our flat?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

Advice would be appreciated as wifi signal dropping is causing serious work-from-home problems for us.
We live in a block of flats in a city centre, so there are many networks close to ours, with some channel interference etc causing problems.

Set-up
Our router (Talktalk Huawei dual channel HG635) is in the sitting room.
We have a devolo powerline adaptor plugged in next to the router, linked by cable. In the sitting room we use one PC about 3 metres from the router & adaptor. We have connected the PC to the devolo adapter by ethernet as signal-dropping was so frequent. There are no walls or other barriers between the router & adaptor and the laptops, PC, and TV with fire-stick (which often drops signal, even late at night for long periods).  At the other end of the hall is a bedroom where two people work & study from home, and the bathroom which also doubles up as an office sometimes. The second Devolo powerline adapter is sited in the hall close these two rooms.  The wifi signal holds better with the adaptor in the hall than when it is plugged into the bedroom socket. But it still drops signal far too often

Wifi analyser shows two instances of the devolo network, with different addresses (? alphanumerics after the same network name), and the router as well. Does this mean there are two SSIDs?

Analyser shows that the channels the powerline adaptors use (most often 6, 11, sometimes 7) often have a lot of interference. But the TV with fire stick often loses the signal when the channel is clear.

We can have two laptops and a remote work station simultaneously using wifi from the second adaptor, while the TV is streaming via Fire Stick and a second remote work station are running in the sitting room (& the PC using the ethernet).

We need to make sure there is a strong and reliable signal at both ends of the flat. The laptops and remote work laptops do not have ethernet sockets.

I don't know how to rationalise the adaptors and network to reduce wifi-dropping, and I don't know if there is a way to run ethernet cable along the hall to the far bedroom to some sort of adaptor or what widget that could broadcast wifi signal strongly into the bedroom and bathroom area.

I don't know if any of the laptops are capable of using 5Ghz wifi - some are 10 years old, others fairly new. The most important work one is new.

Would it be better to buy a much more powerful router, if that is possible?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Use channels 1, 6, or 11 for the 2.4Ghz radio. If it's on auto and jumps in-between non-overlapping channels you will receive even more interference from your neighbors routers. For instance, if you are on channel 7, you will be contending with every device on channel 6 & 11, and get terrible speeds and dropouts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple access points / Switching issues](https://superuser.com/questions/1305544/multiple-access-points-switching-issues)

Comment: Thanks Tim. The speed is fairly good, at least 63 and usually about 73. The devolo adapters must be on auto, as one was on 7 and 11 this morning, but 6 this afternoon. I can see that as soon as a channel clears, the networks swarm to it.  Is there a reason why channels such as 8, 9 and 10 are used less often?

Comment: They shouldn't be on auto, you are describing the auto algorithm failing to do it's job properly. Don't use, channels 2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10... Ever, especially in an urban environment, it will make things ten times worse. Also, for the same reason, don't use 40Mhz wide channels in a scenario like this, it will just exacerbate the problems.

Comment: I bought a [range extender](https://www.amazon.com/NETGEAR-Wi-Fi-Range-Extender-EX3700/dp/B00R92CL5E/ref=asc_df_B00R92CL5E/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=198093101467&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10736574602441826164&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9033294&hvtargid=pla-335129037544&psc=1) for this very purpose.  I can not tell you how well it is working for me and is inexpensive.  The brand does not need to match your router.  What I posted was what I bought.

Comment: Thanks both.  Talktalk have unexpectedly sent a new router, Wifi Hub, so we are trialling it to see if it improves the reliability. So far the Amazon Fire TV Stick streaming is behaving better, but a bit early to tell really.   It looks also as if we do not have the ideal powerline adaptors - both are wifi spots. So we are looking at upgrading to the devolo Magic Next, with ethernet ports to use in case there is still a problem.