# Second wireless router as access point

Tags: networking, wireless-router, modem, wifi-configuration, bridge-router

I'm aware there are a few questions on this topic but none of the solutions seems to work for me. I have a Primary Router (PR) at one end of my house and want to set up an old wireless router (Secondary Router SR) to use to extend the range of my wifi using an Ethernet cable. I think this process is called setting up a second access point but I'm not sure...

The PR has one port, it says "LAN/WAN" under it (I think only LAN active) and the SR only has Ethernet ports.

I have tried multiple configurations but the most common two online are :

PR and SR different IP address 192.168.8.1 and 192.168.8.2, static address for SR, DHCP for PR on, DHCP for SR off, DHCP range outside IP addresses 192.168.8.10 - 192.168.8.255, different SSID and different passwords.

PR and SR same IP address 192.168.8.1, static address for SR, DHCP for PR on, DHCP for SR off, DHCP range outside IP addresses 192.168.8.10 - 192.168.8.255, same SSID and same passwords.

I have ensured that the security is the same, the NAT is turned off for SR, the UPnP is disabled on both, the subnet masks are the same - 255.255.0.0,

Both of the above scenarios will work for 2/3 hours but then the SR will drop all connections. It will come and go as an available network when i try to reconnect, when I do try to connect, I forget the network and enter the password again but it will not connect. All this time I can connect to the PR and have internet access with that router.

I have no idea what configuration what to try next...any ideas?

Comment: Connect them lan port <---> lan port. PR to 192.168.8.1, SR to 192.168.8.254. disable DHCP on SR. Same SSID on both, same security on both, WPA2-psk, AES, same password. The DHCP range should be something like (192.168.8.10 ~ 192.168.8.250).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple access points / Switching issues](https://superuser.com/questions/1305544/multiple-access-points-switching-issues)

Comment: I forgot to mention, channel 1, 6, or 11 for the 2.4Ghz radios, usually when there are only two, you would set them as far apart as possible, i.e PR on channel-1, and SR on channel-11. This setup is called bridging btw

Comment: Okay I have set it up as you have described, it is currently working but I will leave it for 24 hours and see if the connection holds as this is my issue. Don't worry though, if it does, I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: These are comments, not an answer. I have marked this as a duplicate to the linked question/answer. If the community disagrees with that, I will write it all up again as an answer here.

Comment: Okay no problems, I've also just changed the channel of PR to 1 and 11 for SR. Thanks

Comment: Also, I didn't notice it, but the subnet should be a /24 (255.255.255.0) on both routers.

Comment: Both subnets were on 255.255.255.0. This worked for a few hours, I was able to do a video call and the quality was perfect but when I woke up this morning, my phone could not connect to the SR. The SR was showing up as 'available', when i click on it, it tried to connect but fails without giving a reason. I then tried my laptop using wireless but still wouldn't connect. I then tried using an Ethernet cable with my laptop and it works with no issues. What could the reason for this be?

Comment: It sounds like a either a software or hardware problem with the SR. Try upgrading it's firmware if any is available. If not just replace it.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I had a feeling it would be, there wasn't an option to update the firmware so I've replaced it and everything works perfectly. Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome. 